# ExcelVBA: SaveCopyAs won't allow edits to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to create code that allows me to edit a workbook, create multiple copies, then edit those copies and save them.  I'm hoping someone can talk me through the logic here because I've tried everything I can think of more than once.

```
Sub RemoveViolations()

Dim fBook As Workbook
Dim fBook2 As Workbook
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
fSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
fPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set fBook = ActiveWorkbook

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & LastRow)
c = UCase(Trim(c.Value))
fName2 = Replace(fName, "swpaSumRPT-", "swpaSumRPT-" & c & "-")
fBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & c, Operator:=xlFilterValues
If fBook2 Is Nothing Then fBook.SaveCopyAs fPath & "\" & fName2
Set fBook2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\" & fName2)
MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Next c

End Sub
```

I'm not sure why I can't keep running the code from the original document after the new copy workbook is opened and activated.  I've seen examples of others doing this and I THOUGHT I had properly followed the instructions.  It appears that once the new workbook is open, the code stops running.  I'm hoping you can  help me understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "allow edits to new Workbook"? Does the newly created workbook open? If not, it may be a problem with the string defining its name. Please, edit your code and also place the part which defines "fName". At the first glance, a file name to be saved, ending in "_" is not appropriate. It looks missing the necessary extension... Is the workbook a 'xlsx' type? If yes, you should add this extension after "_" character. If not, add the necessary (existing) extension.

Comment: I meant "_", but I do not understand what's happened...

Comment: I've edited my code to make it clearer, I hope...  My issue is, I think, fundamental to the nature of an opened and activated workbook.  I don't quite understand it.

Comment: The code doesn't "stop running", but `fbook2` is only ever being assigned in the first iteration of that loop, so `fbook.SaveCopyAs` only runs once. Have you tried setting a breakpoint (F9) in the loop and step-through debugging (F8) to see if the code runs line by line the way you expect it to?

Comment: @Mathieu, I say that the code stops because it won't run any code below Worbooks.Open.  I need to be able to make changes to the new workbooks.  My intention is to remove all visible rows (from the autofilter) and then remove the autofilter so that only the "c" values remain. Working on the debugging now.

Comment: Truthfully, I don't even know how to use the debugging tools. I'm missing some basic knowledge from way back...

Comment: When a breakpoint is hit, the current instruction is highlighted in yellow (you can drag the yellow arrow to any line in that scope to *make it* the next statement to run); F8 executes that one statement (stepping *through*); Shift+F8 does the same but steps *over*. While in that state, execution is effectively paused, and you can inspect the state and values of all objects and variables in scope (hover a variable to see a tooltip with its value). Hope it helps!

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon when I step through the code, it seems to work fine

Comment: If the code isn't doing what it's supposed to be doing, then *something somewhere* isn't working the way it should. Unless I'm missing something, `fbook2` being only assigned once should be a problem; stepping through and tracking the active workbook and sheet should help: I'd think one of these things isn't what it needs to be at one point or another during execution.

Comment: The filter is applied on row 3, is row 1 or row 2 empty ?

Comment: @CDP1802 No.  The original workbook has data that the operator can see.

Comment: It looks to me like you have values (strings) in column `B` where for each value you want to create a workbook that will contain this value in its name and only this value in column `B`. Note that if you only need one worksheet in those workbooks, you could e.g. use a simple `Sheet1.Copy` to create a new workbook containing only this worksheet, process it, and save it. Please do clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not toatlly sure what you want to do, but you can try the code below.

If you have more than one workbook open and you want to save all the workbooks, if you want to save all open workbooks, you can use the code below:

```
Sub SaveAllWorkbooks()
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks
wb.Save
Next wb
End Sub
```

Notice the `Dim wb As Workbook`.  You should specifically reference all objects.  Also, make sure everything is managed in the same instance of Excel that you are working with.  As I know, a new instance of Excel can't 'see' a current instance of Excel.  Check out the ink below when you have some free time.

https://trumpexcel.com/vba-workbook/

Comment: The question is about SaveCopyAs

Answer (score 0):

Try this adapted code, please:

```
Sub RemoveViolations()
 Dim fBook As Workbook, fBook2 As Workbook, lastRow As Long, fName As String, strC As String
 Dim c As Range, fSheet As String, fPath As String, fName2 As String, justName As String

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
 fName = ActiveWorkbook.name
 fSheet = ActiveSheet.name
 fPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
 Set fBook = ActiveWorkbook

 For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
    strC = UCase(Trim(c.Value))
    '________________________________________________________________________
    justName = Split(fName, ".")(0)
    fName2 = Replace(justName, "swpaSumRPT-", "swpaSumRPT-" & strC & "-")
    fName2 = fName2 & "." & Split(fName, ".")(1)
    '________________________________________________________________________
    fBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & c.value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    If fBook2 Is Nothing Then fBook.SaveCopyAs fPath & "\" & fName2
    Set fBook2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\" & fName2)
    MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.name)
    Set fBook2 = Nothing
 Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the point of your edit, since the rename seems to work already.

Comment: @CaptMAZing: There were two edits. One to be sure that `Criteria1` will take the value of `c` cell, even if Excel may guess and the second to make `fBook2` nothing in order to allow the loop continuing...  The third one only removed the extra `Set` word...

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 steps, copy the files and then open them. This avoids changing the active workbook inside your loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveViolations()

    Dim fbook As Workbook, fbook2 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim fname As String, fname2 As String
    Dim fpath As String, s As String
    Dim copies As New Collection
    
    Set fbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = fbook.ActiveSheet
    fname = fbook.Name
    fpath = fbook.Path
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' make copies and store name in a collection
    For Each c In ws.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
         
        s = UCase(Trim(c.Value))
        fname2 = Replace(fname, "swpaSumRPT-", "swpaSumRPT-" & s & "-")
        'Debug.Print s, fname2
         
        ws.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & c, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        fbook.SaveCopyAs fpath & "\" & fname2
         
        copies.Add fname2
        
    Next c
    ws.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter ' remove
          
    ' open workbooks and delete visible rows
    If MsgBox(copies.Count & " copies made. Do you want to open/edit them all ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Open") = vbYes Then
     
        Dim obj, rng As Range
        For Each obj In copies
            Set fbook2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath & "\" & obj)
            ' avoid header 3 rows
            Set rng = fbook2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(3)
            ' delete visible rows
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            fbook2.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter ' remove filter
        Next
    End If
     
End Sub
```

Comment: very interesting... and likely the cause of my failure.  Others have pointed out potential issues, but this may very well be the source of my troubles